# word not getting broken to new line

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, justification

In the first paragraph of the following document, the word `mathematical` is not getting broken across lines and this produces a misalignment with a wrong justification of the text. I know I can force the break with `-\-` in whatever point I decide but is not there any automatic way to do it?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}



\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}

\newcommand{\ressubheadingNew}[5]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}}{\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}\indent \textbf{Thesis}: {#5}}\\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\Huge MyName} \\
peter@neverland.com & Mobile: 018923123890123890123890 \\
 & \\
\end{tabularx}
\\
\vspace{-2mm}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut mathematical labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

\vspace{-4mm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%SECTION%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Bachelor studies in Flight}{September 2020 - October 2020}{Development of flight}
    \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Master studies in Flight}{October 2020 - November 2020}{Development of swimming skills}
        \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Postgraduate studies in Flight}{October 2020 - November 2020}{Example of a very long sentence in another section where, unexpectedly, the word mathematical got broken}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You have `\raggedright` on your 5th line...

Comment: How can I make just that paragraph ignore the command?

Comment: since almost all of the other text is in tables, why not simply remove \raggedright at the top level if you do not want the whole document set raggedright. . As the posted answer shows, you could use justify from ragged2e but almost always if that needs to be use it is correcting  an incorrect setting earlier in the document.

Comment: never use `tabularx` without an `X` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the package `ragged2e` and use the environment `justify` as following

```
\begin{justify}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut mathematical labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
\end{justify}
```

[image: y]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `\raggedright` in your preamble.

However, you're misusing the tools, I'm afraid, in particular `tabularx`.

There is a much simpler way to set up your CV.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\geometry{
  headheight=0in,
  headsep=0in,
  textheight=9.5in,
  textwidth=7in,
}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}% ???
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\ressubheadingNew}[5]{%
  \textbf{#1}\dotfill #2\\*
  \textit{#3}\dotfill \textit{#4}\\*
  \hspace*{2em}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2em}
     \textbf{Thesis}: #5
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
}
\iffalse % keep for the record
\newcommand{\ressubheadingNew}[5]{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
    \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{%
      \setlength{\parindent}{4ex}\indent \textbf{Thesis}: {#5}%
    }
  \end{tabular*}%
  \par\vspace{2pt}%
}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\Huge MyName} \\[1ex]
peter@neverland.com & Mobile: 018923123890123890123890 \\
 & \\
\end{tabular*}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut mathematical labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%SECTION%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ressubheadingNew
  {University of Neverland}
  {Neverland}
  {Bachelor studies in Flight}
  {September 2020 - October 2020}
  {Development of flight}

\ressubheadingNew
  {University of Neverland}
  {Neverland}
  {Master studies in Flight}
  {October 2020 - November 2020}
  {Development of swimming skills}

\ressubheadingNew
  {University of Neverland}
  {Neverland}
  {Postgraduate studies in Flight}
  {October 2020 - November 2020}
  {Example of a very long sentence in another section where, unexpectedly,
   the word mathematical got broken}

\end{document}
```

Add the other packages you really need. Change `\dotfill` to `\hfill` if you don't want leaders.

I kept a better definition for the main macro based on `tabular*` rather than `tabularx` (which needs an `X` column to properly work.

[image]